# Cannot read value of scope/elm in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to fire an event when user finish typing into input field and I'm stuck at reading the value which was entered :(

Here is my code:

## js

```
var subtitlesApp = angular.module('subtitlesApp', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies']);

subtitlesApp.directive('ngModelOnblur', function ($timeout) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
        elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
    elm.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.$apply(function(imdb_id) {
            console.log(imdb_id)
                })
            });         
        }
    };
})
```

## html

```
<input id="subtitle-imdb_id" type="text" ng-model="subtitle.imdb_id" ng-model-onblur/>
```

I'm getting:

```
a {$id: "004", this: a, $$listeners: Object, $parent: e, $$asyncQueue: Array[0]…}
```

Instead of getting the value of elm or imdb_id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not unbind the input event. And you can get the data via scope.

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
    elm.unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
    elm.bind('blur', function () {
        scope.$apply(function (imdb_id) {
            console.log(scope.subtitle.imdb_id)
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is a scope, as the first argument passed to the method $apply is current scope.

If you want to get the value of `ngModel`, you have to call `$eval` on that scope, as in:

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
    elm.bind('blur', function() {
      scope.$apply(function(scope) {
        console.log(scope.$eval(attr.ngModel));
      });
    });         
    }
};
```

Beside, rather do not unbind the events.